# How do I handle Fiat payments?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, eth-2.0

Is there a good method/way of handling Fiat money in my dapp? Is there anything like Stripe but for use on blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Unlock Protocol](https://unlock-protocol.com/) that you could use to setup paywalls. And there's also [LimePay](https://limepay.io/), that's more general purpose.

I would presume that those are still kinda experimental though. I would recommend a thorough security assessment before deciding to integrate.